# Does window state persist after navigation?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, back-button

Suppose I'm in `page0` and call this javascript:

```
window.flag = 1
```

and then navigate away to `page1` and hit the back button. When `page0` loads, but before the flag is set, will `window.flag` still be `1`, or will it be `undefined`? In other words, does window state for a page persist?

I would have thought this was a very simple thing to clarify, but I can't find documentation about it anywhere.

Comment: You said you navigated away, you lost your page and its state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

JavaScript is client-side and non-persistent. Unless you actively save values somehow, the results of called JavaScripts are *not* retained.

If you do want to save a value or object, look into `localStorage` or cookies.

Comment: This matches my testing, and I will see about localStorage for my needs. Thanks. It seems like a fundamental thing, and I guess everyone knows it, but where is it documented?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank I don't actually know where (or if) it's documented - but you can verify it for yourself just by reloading a page.